# Reference DLL from NuGet folder inside ASP.NET Core project on full .NET framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, msbuild

I have created a new ASP.NET Core project which targets the full .NET 4.6 framework. So essentially what I want is to create an ASP.NET Core web application with the new .csproj format and the new dotnet tooling, but still target the full framework because we have many dependencies which cannot be ported that quickly to .NET Core.

There are some NuGet packages that include many DLLs, but after adding a `PackageReference` it only copies one DLL into the bin folder of the web application. Other DLLs I need to manually reference.

For example:

`<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="CustomDll">
        <HintPath>..\packages\CustomPackage\version\lib\CustomDll.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
</ItemGroup>`

Now the problem is that with the new tooling and NuGet versions there is no packages folder under the solution path. It is typically in my users folder under `.nuget\packages\...`.

Is there a macro that I can use with the new MSBuild to reference the global nuget folder or a setting that I can change so that the build actually copies all NuGet packages under the solution directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the dll in the NuGet package is placed directly in the `lib` folder and not `lib\net45` which would enable the automatic tooling in that case. (The NuGet package has probably been manually assembled).

As a workaround, you can set the `HintPath` to `$(NuGetPackageRoot)the.package.name\1.0.0\lib\the.dll`.

Comment: Seems like that in the latest .NET Core SDK $(NuGetPackageFolders) has been dropped, but $(NuGetPackageRoot) works instead!

Comment: Updated. It should have been `NuGetPackageRoot` all along